# Is this PCI analog TV card compatible with Ubuntu/Mythbuntu, KW-PC134-A?

Tags: hardware, mythbuntu, mythtv, tv-tuner

Ask this question to the sellers directly in my country is a waste of time.

Will this card work with Ubuntu? (assume 13.XX/14.XX)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I looked up the TV adapter model KW-PC134-A you mentioned ( http://global.kworld-global.com/main/prod_in.aspx?mnuid=1248&modid=6&prodid=1542&flag=1 ) I'll have to say the chances are slim, I had the USB version of the Kworld TV adapters and they are mostly aimed at Windows users.

I'll suggest perhaps looking into the Hauppage models, they have better support in the Linux world.

Here's a good source of info for your reference if you want to stick with the Kworld models http://linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/KWorld

and here for Hauppage http://linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Hauppauge

those are the list of known working models for both.

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid of buying it too. I know some KWorld adapters works on Linux, but this one is not listed in any site I visited. The presence of some KWorld adapters in some lists made me hope, but cannot find this exact model listed anywhere. I will consult that site when looking into the next candidate.

Answer (score 0):

Well the best and easiest way to find out is to boot up Mythbuntu LiveCD (or USB) and let it see if it detects it. ;)

Comment: I do not own the card yet. I'm asking to then go and buy it.